# Stop & Start SignalR-Objc SRHubConnection multiple times makes connection unstable

Tags: ios, objective-c, signalr, signalr.client

In one of our iOS app using [SignalR-ObjC](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC), the connection is working fine across the app. 
As in iOS app in background is not responsive and can't receive signalr messages. So we have following implementation:

```
SRHubConnection *connection = [[SRHubConnection alloc] initWithURLString:url useDefault:NO]
```

- App goes to Background: [connection stop]; Stop the connection.
- App comes to Foreground: [connection start]; Create a new connection object and start it. .

But if we switch between background and foreground 3 to 4 times continuously, makes the connection unstable and it do not connects again and throws following error.

```
[HTTP_BASED_TRANSPORT]
Cleandisconnectfailed.ErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomainCode=-1001"The request timed out."UserInfo={
  NSUnderlyingError=0x159283ae0{
    ErrorDomain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetworkCode=-1001"The request timed out."UserInfo={
      NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http: //websiteurl.net/signalr/abort?clientProtocol=1.3.0.0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22Name%22%3A%22hotlinechathub%22%7D%5D&connectionToken=wxhidka/adfaf/MDf57llaaBz22i55k7%2BUVNX4DHCixM1hX1k%2BhVy/Yi1FwnwMdwhzIrgpaeD5E4oC%2B702UnosdkQL1z2FrgebWw2uY0qCh9LG0Zfj9ZdY2pRG0&transport=longPolling,
      NSErrorFailingURLKey=http: //website.net/signalr/abort?clientProtocol=1.3.0.0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22Name%22%3A%22hotlinechathub%22%7D%5D&connectionToken=gcukXaFIN/wm4ilNrj/MDf57llaaBz22i55k7%2BUVNX4DHCixM1hX1k%2BhVy/Yi1FwnwMdwhzIrgpaeD5E4oC%2B702UnosdkQL1z2FrgebWw2uY0qCh9LG0Zfj9ZdY2pRG0&transport=longPolling,
      _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102,
      _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4,
      NSLocalizedDescription=Therequesttimedout.
    }
  },
  NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http: //website.net/signalr/abort?clientProtocol=1.3.0.0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22Name%22%3A%22hotlinechathub%22%7D%5D&connectionToken=gcukXaFIN/wm4ilNrj/MDf57llaaBz22i55k7%2BUVNX4DHCixM1hX1k%2BhVy/Yi1FwnwMdwhzIrgpaeD5E4oC%2B702UnosdkQL1z2FrgebWw2uY0qCh9LG0Zfj9ZdY2pRG0&transport=longPolling,
  NSErrorFailingURLKey=http: //website.net/signalr/abort?clientProtocol=1.3.0.0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22Name%22%3A%22hotlinechathub%22%7D%5D&connectionToken=gcukXaFIN/wm4ilNrj/MDf57llaaBz22i55k7%2BUVNX4DHCixM1hX1k%2BhVy/Yi1FwnwMdwhzIrgpaeD5E4oC%2B702UnosdkQL1z2FrgebWw2uY0qCh9LG0Zfj9ZdY2pRG0&transport=longPolling,
  _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4,
  _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102,
  NSLocalizedDescription=Therequesttimedout.
}
```

And error:

```
[CONNECTION]
negotiationfailedErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomainCode=-1001 
"The request timed out."UserInfo={Same as displayed above}
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to stop SRHubConnection from going to such unstable state and start the new connection without error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not calling `start` or `stop` multiple times, on connection object.
Calling them multiple times can lead connection to be in unstable state.

Comment: That fixed my problem. I was calling start two times from different methods.